# API successfull called, but not displayed

Tags: android, api, retrofit2

i am  trying to call local API server using retrofit, in my Logcat shows that the API success called, but in my app there is nothing displayed. how i can fix this issue? and here is my code :

interface.java :

```
public interface Service {
 @GET("vocabulary/id/*")
 Call<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> getVocabMaster();
}
```

Vocab Master.java to collect data from API :

```
public class VocabMaster implements Serializable {

private BigDecimal vocab_id;
private String hanzi_t;
private String hanzi_s;
private String pinyin;
private BigDecimal level_id;
private List<VocabMeaning> meaning;

public BigDecimal getVocab_id() {
    return vocab_id;
}

public void setVocab_id(BigDecimal vocab_id) {
    this.vocab_id = vocab_id;
}

public String getHanzi_t() {
    return hanzi_t;
}

public void setHanzi_t(String hanzi_t) {
    this.hanzi_t = hanzi_t;
}

public String getHanzi_s() {
    return hanzi_s;
}

public void setHanzi_s(String hanzi_s) {
    this.hanzi_s = hanzi_s;
}

public String getPinyin() {
    return pinyin;
}

public void setPinyin(String pinyin) {
    this.pinyin = pinyin;
}

public List<VocabMeaning> getMeaning() {
    return meaning;
}

public void setMeaning(List<VocabMeaning> meaning) {
    this.meaning = meaning;
}

public BigDecimal getLevel_id() {
    return level_id;
}

public void setLevel_id(BigDecimal level_id) {
    this.level_id = level_id;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "VocabMaster{" +
            "vocab_id=" + vocab_id +
            ", hanzi_t='" + hanzi_t + '\'' +
            ", hanzi_s='" + hanzi_s + '\'' +
            ", pinyin='" + pinyin + '\'' +
            ", level_id=" + level_id +
            ", meaning=" + meaning +
            '}';
  }
}
```

And this is MainActivity.java :

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView rvReligiVideo;
List<VocabMaster> vocabMasters = new ArrayList<>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rvReligiVideo = findViewById(R.id.rvReligi);
    initReligiVideo();
    loadReligiVideo();

}

private void initReligiVideo() {
    LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    rvReligiVideo.setLayoutManager(layout);
    VocabAdapter ar = new VocabAdapter(vocabMasters);
    rvReligiVideo.setAdapter(ar);

}

//=========== Request to API ==========
private void loadReligiVideo() {
    Call<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> call = ServicesFactory.getService().getVocabMaster();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> call, Response<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isSuccessful()) {
                List<VocabMaster> data = response.body().data;
                if (data != null) {
                    vocabMasters.clear();
                    vocabMasters.addAll(data);
                    rvReligiVideo.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
  }

}
```

logcat on android studio :

[image]

JSON Data Structure :

[image]

Here is my Adapter :

```
public class VocabAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
List<VocabMaster> data;

public VocabAdapter(List<VocabMaster> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vocabulary_model, null);
    return new VH(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    VocabMaster vm = data.get(position);
    VH vh = (VH) holder;

    vh.hanziS.setText(vm.getHanzi_s());
    vh.hanziT.setText(vm.getHanzi_t());
    vh.pinyin.setText(vm.getPinyin());

    vh.sound.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Sound", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    vh.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    vh.share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Share", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (data == null) ? 0 : data.size();
}

public class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView hanziS;
    TextView hanziT;
    TextView pinyin;
    TextView desc;
    ImageView sound, share, favorite;
    Context context;

    public VH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        hanziS = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hanziS);
        hanziT = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hanziT);
        pinyin = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pinyin);
        desc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtDesc);
        sound = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgSpeaker);
        share = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgShare);
        favorite = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFavotite);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: If you aren't seeing anything, check your XML. Your code has no Log statements, so how are you getting that logcat?

Comment: Can you also add the constructor for `VocabAdapter `?

Comment: my adapter already have adapter

Comment: I have a guess on what might be wrong, but in order to be sure, I have to see the code `VocabAdapter `. Please post this code also

Comment: please see updated above..

Comment: are you sure List<VocabMaster> data variable inside VocabAdapter contains data?

Comment: you can see VocabMaster above and JSON data structure above..

Comment: Pass **ViewGroup** and **attachToRoot** parameter while inflating the views. For more information check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: @naresh how to do that? iam newbie here..

Comment: Go through this [Working with RecyclerView](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Answer (score 0):

i did some changes in your code... use this

```
  private VocabAdapter ar;
private void initReligiVideo() {
    LinearLayoutManager layout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
    rvReligiVideo.setLayoutManager(layout);
     ar = new VocabAdapter(vocabMasters);
    rvReligiVideo.setAdapter(ar);
}

    private void loadReligiVideo() {
    Call<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> call = ServicesFactory.getService().getVocabMaster();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> call, Response<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body().isSuccessful()) {
                List<VocabMaster> data = response.body().data;
                if (data != null) {
                    ar.setVocoList(data);
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse<List<VocabMaster>>> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    });
}
```

**Add this method in your adapter Class**

```
 public void setVocoList(List<VocabMaster> list){
    if(list!=null)
        data=list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not change adapter's list when you have new list.

```
   //incorrect except that the adapter is first time set to recyclerview and setVocoList is called before recyclerview.setAdater
    public void setVocoList(List<VocabMaster> list){
        if(list!=null)
            data=list;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //correct
    private List<VocabMaster>  datas = new ArrayList()
    public void setVocoList(List<VocabMaster> list){
            if(list==null) return;
            datas.clear();
            datas.addAll(list);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```